# Delete inedxedDB on page load using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, indexeddb

I want to delete my indexedDB every time my home page is loaded. My homepage is running on localhost:3000.

This is my application:

[image: check this image]

Comment: The picture doesn't add anything to your question. Maybe add a little more info about your application and how it is connected to the database?

Answer (score 1):

In created() method of your home page you need to call below method

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase(databaseName);
```